# how to fix error 'no rule to make target %.o, needed by all. stop'

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

When I type make and hit enter, it says:

```
no rule to make target %.o, needed by all. stop'.
```

This is my makefile:

```
CC=g++
LDFLAGS=""

all: %.o %.h
    $(CC) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o bin

%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) -c $<
```

These are the contents of my directory:

```sh
$ ls
main.cpp makefile
```

I'm new to GNU make and just learned to use automatic variables. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

% is for substituting patterns, which is what you want when defining a rule for a single module (like you did), but not what you want as the dependency list of 'all'. A % will expand to a *single* value.
Instead, you want an actual wildcard (like in the shell expansion) to match all *.o files. So, change your target definition to

```
all: *.o *.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question, but this is not right:

```
LDFLAGS=""
```

make doesn't parse quotes, so you've set the variable `LDFLAGS` to the literal string `""` (two double-quotes).  When you use that in your recipe:

```
$(CC) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o bin
```

it will be as if you'd typed:

```
g++ ... "" -o bin
```

which is a syntax error (you're passing an empty argument to `g++`.  If you want an empty variable you just write:

```
LDFLAGS =
```

Now, your problem.  This is not a pattern rule:

```
all: %.o %.h
```

A pattern rule must have a pattern in the target (left-hand side of the colon).  Since this is an explicit rule, the prerequisites (the right-hand side of the colon) are the literal strings `%.o` and `%.h`.  Make doesn't know how to build a file named `%.o` so it fails.

It's not really clear what you expect this rule to do, so I can't say more than that.